# How to hide/block certain elements by ID in awesomium in VB.NET?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, awesomium

I'm looking for a code to hide/block specific elements by ID in VB.NET?

Working native Webbrowser Code

```
 Dim ele = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("header")
 If ele IsNot Nothing Then
     ele.Style = "Display:none"
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript (`ExecuteJavascript`), something like

```
WebBrowser1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none'");
```

Or you can use `CustomCSS` property in `WebPreferences`.